# Symbols not copied correctly while getting the page source

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am trying to get the source of a webpage using the following code:

```
public static String getFile(String sUrl) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    // Prepare a request object
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(sUrl);

    // Execute the request
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);

    // Examine the response status
    System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());

    //status code should be 200
    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {
        return null; 
    }

    // Get hold of the response entity
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
    // to worry about connection release
    if (entity != null) {
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
            // do something useful with the response
            String s = reader.readLine();

            while (s != null) {
                b.append(s);
                b.append("\n");
                s = reader.readLine();
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // In case of an IOException the connection will be released
            // back to the connection manager automatically
            throw ex;

        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            // In case of an unexpected exception you may want to abort
            // the HTTP request in order to shut down the underlying
            // connection and release it back to the connection manager.
            httpget.abort();
            throw ex;

        } finally {
            // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
            instream.close();
        }

        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

    return b.toString();
}
```

It works fine, but certain symbols like &nbsp, - , single quotes etc. are not getting copied correctly.
I try to save the page source as a `text/html` type into `amazon s3` and display it by accessing the page saved in the `s3 server`.

The symbols that I mentioned above are displayed as `�` .
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @Joop Eggen , I tried the following code:  ' String enc = "Windows-1252";
             ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
             Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
             if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(enc)) 
             {
                 enc = charset.toString();
             }'   and I found  Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1. I tried to use Windows-1252 and utf-8 without trying to use the content-type of entity. but the issue still occurs, &nbsp in the origial document is now displayed as ?.....thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you are reading the content with the encoding of the page, else your system default encoding would be used (which apparently is not the correct one as you have seen):

```
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
      new InputStreamReader(instream, entity.getContentEncoding()));
```

Answer (score 1):

First one need to specify the encoding that the InputStreamReader uses. Your version of the constructor takes the default encoding on your system.

The encoding could be delivered in the headers. It defaults to ISO-8859-1 but (Latin-1) but in reality is Windows-1252 (Windows Latin-1).

```
String charset = "Windows-1252"; // Can be used as default.
String enc = entity.getContentEncoding(); // Or from Content-Type.
if (enc != null) {
    charset = enc;
}

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(instream, charset));
```

For HTML entities, apache has:

```
String s = ...
s = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHTML4(s);
```